# PySpark: Create new column based on null values in other columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl

I am working on a PySpark transformation to create a new column based on null values in another columns. Below is the sample input dataframe:

[Input DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4WRk.png)

This is the expected output dataframe:

[Output Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2pds.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hi welcome to stack overflow. It is probably a good idea to read [the question best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
To build a column like that, the easiest way will probably be to build a column with your desired text corrosponding to nulls in each original column.
for example

```
    cols = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    new_cols = ["A_nulls", "B_nulls", "C_nulls", "D_nulls", "new_col"]

    df = source_df.withColumn("new_col", F.lit("Null Columns:"))
    df = df.withColumn("A_nulls", F.when(
        F.col("A").isNotNull(), F.lit("A,"))
        .otherwise("")
    )
    df = df.withColumn("B_nulls", F.when(
        F.col("B").isNotNull(), F.lit("B,"))
        .otherwise(""))

    df = df.withColumn("C_nulls", F.when(
        F.col("C").isNotNull(), F.lit("C,"))
        .otherwise(""))

    df = df.withColumn("D_nulls", F.when(
        F.col("D").isNotNull(), F.lit("D,"))
        .otherwise(""))

    df = df.select(*cols, F.concat(*new_cols).alias("NewCol"))
```

If you want to remove the trailing `,` you can use `F.regexp_replace("new_col", ",$", "")` which should trim those.